# Asp.Net Core 2.1 Using ViewComponents between Head tags for Getting Metadata Dynamicly

Tags: asp.net-core, meta-tags, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to add metadatas to layout page for SEO dynamicly from admin panel. Sample:

```
<meta content="" name="description" />
<meta content="XXX" name="author" />
```

In MVC5, I use:
`<head>
    @Html.Action("GetMetatags", "Home") 
</head>`

and easily get them. 
But in Asp.Net Core 2.1, I try to use ViewComponents instead of partial view like this:

```
<head> 
     @await Component.InvokeAsync("MetaDatasForSEO") 
</head>
```

The problem: I can get metadatas correctly but not between `<head>` tags. Just in `<Body>` tag...So it doesnt works. Thanks for help...

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue, it works correctly when appending `@await Component.InvokeAsync("MetaDatasForSEO") ` in `_Layout.cshtml`. Check the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W7mo.png)

Comment: Thanks Tao. I think there should be a latency because of async process and getting data from database and I think, the result metadatas dislay in body because of this latency.
Try to get metadatas with js.
But after your message, i have checked again the other codes carefully and noticed the viewcomponent cshtml:
It seems: 

    @Model.Metatags

So, that string result display in body as string, not hidden metatags.
Then changed it

    @Html.Raw(Model.Metatags). 
Now it works. thanks...

Comment: Glad it works now.